# Apache2 subdomain

Tags: php, apache2

I have a question about apache2 and subdomains together with php.

I have 1 "app" running but i want 3 different subdomains pointing towards it, url has to stay the same, but the "app" needs to know which domain it runs on (i tought of a php var or something).

```
app location: /var/www/app

d1.url.be
d2.url.be
d3.url.be
```

So all of these domains have to point to the same location, but with a ?domain=d1 var in url.
Trying to figure this out for a while, can't get it right...

Answer (score 0):

> So all of these domains have to point to the same location, but with a ?domain=d1 var in url.

You're overcomplicating the solution. There is no need to make Apache remap the URL so that information is in the query string.

In PHP the hostname is available through `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.